# How to remove 5V from circuit so that my meter reads correctly after LiFePO4 upgrade on golf cart?

Tags: voltage, lithium-ion, voltage-measurement

A while ago, I upgraded my lead acid batteries to LiFePO4 for my golf cart.  The state of charge ("SOC"/battery gauge/voltmeter) is for a 48V cart but the new batteries put out 53.x volts so it always shows as 100% full and more or less just functions as an on/off light.

I've been wondering if there is a way to trick the meter and step it down 5V so that the SOC meter will read correctly.  I was looking at buck converters based on another question asked here but that seems like it would just always try to deliver a constant voltage.

This SOC is in a very small space so I really would like a very small solution so that I don't have to do a bunch of rewiring.

[This is the SOC meter](https://www.shopezgo.com/33636g05#/s/EZG//33636G05//1/y). I can't find any specs on what the actual meter voltage range is but I'm guessing pulling off 5V would put it right in range (if possible.)

EDIT: As requested, here's my best stab at a schematic:

[image: SOC Meter Wiring]

I'm guessing for testing the quickest thing would be to pop a 4.7V Zener onto the positive side of the circuit.

Comment: Please show a schematic. Can you put a 4.7 V Zener in series?

Comment: The relationship of voltage to state of charge for the LiFePO4 batteries isn’t the same as the lead-acid, so just subtracting 5V probably won’t work.

Comment: Somebody has asked this before and got nowhere. You're probably better off just getting another meter and wiring to the battery and sticking it on the dash than trying to modify what is there.

Comment: The schematic on this is actually super simple, it's just two wires directly connected to the battery terminals.  

In my case, positive and negative wires go directly from the SOC meter to the battery terminals.  It's installed in an "On The Fly Holder" [Console addon like this one](https://www.golfcartmadness.com/product/otf-dash-mount/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a series resistor so that the scale will be 0-56 V, but that might not properly drive the display, unless it has a separate power supply. The series zener, as suggested, might work better. But in either case, a capacitor across the meter might be needed.

A better inexpensive way to estimate SOC might be a running time counter, but it would depend on how consistent your usage is, and would need to stop timing when the motor isn't running.

The best DIY solution might be a current to frequency circuit and a counter, to measure A-h energy used. And there are inexpensive combination V / A / W / W-h meters.

Answer (score 5):

A lead acid battery voltage drops proportionally as it discharges, while LiFePO4 batteries have a much steadier voltage until 85% of capacity is used, then a sudden drop off. Here's a discharge curve from [batterypowertips.com](https://www.batterypowertips.com/how-to-read-battery-discharge-curves-faq/)
[image]

Your simplest bet is to just re-interpret what your SOC meter shows. If it shows anything less than 100%, you're on your last 15% of capacity from the LiFePO4.

You can buy small modules for a few dollars that read DC voltage directly, but I don't think it's worth the trouble of the mounting and rewiring. The voltage still won't give a reliable indication of remaining capacity until you're near the end. A *coulomb counter* measures cumulative current flow and would work, but you won't find a ready-made one to mount there.

Comment: Currently it never leaves the 100% full mark at all.  Any indication that some usage has happend, so that I could at least get a quick clue without looking at my more robust energy meter is the goal.   Unless you happen to know of a meter that fits in that vertical slot.  It's a custom golf cart so this is an aesthetics thing too.

Answer (score 1):

### You need a different measurement strategy for LiFePO4 fuel gauging

Lead acid batteries can be judged (reasonably accurately) from their voltage. This is what your current "fuel gauge" does. That approach won't work with a lithium chemistry battery (as you've discovered).

[image: Lithium Ion vs Lead Acid discharge curves]
[credit: Pilot Group UK](https://www.thepilotgroup.co.uk/lithium-ion-battery-vs-lead-acid-battery/)

Lithium batteries have the *very* desirable attribute of maintaining their voltage over the majority of their discharge cycle, making the voltage-only approach mostly useless.

### You need to measure energy instead

Energy is measured in Joule's and charge is measured in Coulomb's. The relationship is:

`Joule per Coulomb = Volt`

Commercially, energy based fuel gauges are known as "Coulomb Counters". Here's a relatively common and economical example from Renogy:

[image]
[credit: Renogy, Inc.](https://www.renogy.com/)

It's a "Universal" battery gauge because you must tell it the size, voltage, and derating parameters of the battery you are actually measuring:

[image]
[credit: Renogy, Inc.](https://www.renogy.com/)

...and then you connect it in the *low side* electrical return path so it can measure the voltage and current.

[image]
[credit: Renogy, Inc.](https://www.renogy.com/)

Due the wide range of battery systems in use in carts, scooters, and other small electric vehicles, there are many OEM's for this type of panel meter and most units cost less than $100 all in.

Comment: DrFriedParts - Hi, To comply with the [site rule](/help/referencing) for content copied into a post from elsewhere, can you please add a link next to each image, back to the original source webpage for that image? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Re: chart; the link was embedded, but now it's directly in the text. Links for the commercial images are not provided to comply with the anti-promotion rules. Sufficient citing was provided and remains visible.

Comment: @DrFriedParts My understanding is that the only anti-promotion rules are that you can't ask for recommendations and that you shouldn't promote products you have some connection to without disclosing that connection. Images always need sources.

Comment: @DrFriedParts - As *Hearth* says, the [promotion](/help/promotion) rule doesn't apply here (unless you are affiliated with something you're linking). If you copy content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere onto SE, *you have no choice* about whether or not to follow the [referencing rule](/help/referencing) - that requires a *link* (back to an online source webpage - see the rule for details of book-type content). I saw you originally had the company name for the 1st image in the alt text, but it wasn't the required *link* to the source webpage. Can you add the other links? Thanks

Comment: These are great, I have something similar also installed but the completion-ist in me wants that SOC meter to at least move some!  It's kind of permanently installed, there aren't many vertical meters out there to fill the hole.